# Python map() list of lists maintains references to sublist elements

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I was told that map() was pretty fast (https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/), so I tried to use it to copy a list of lists, without caring about mutability, I called tuple on each sublist like so:

```
sheet = [['a','a','a'],
         ['a','a','a'],
         ['a','a','a'],
         ['a','a','a'],
         ['a','a','a']]

newsheet1 = map(tuple,sheet)
```

but discovered that the map object maintains references to the original sheet sublist elements, demonstrable by changing a value in sheet, the change will be reflected in the map object:

```
sheet[0][0] = 'CHANGED'

for r in newsheet1:
    print (r)
```

prints:

```
('CHANGED', 'a', 'a')
('a', 'a', 'a')
('a', 'a', 'a')
('a', 'a', 'a')
('a', 'a', 'a')
```

So I tried making a copy with list comprehension instead:

```
newsheet2 = [tuple(row) for row in sheet]

sheet[0][0] = 'CHANGED'

print (newsheet2[0])
```

prints:

```
('a', 'a', 'a')
```

So the list comprehension doesn't keep the original element references, but is it much slower than using map()? and is there any way I could use map() without maintaining references here if it's quicker?

I guess my question boils down to fastest way to copy a list of lists

Comment: The difference is that `map` is **lazily evaluated** in Python 3.x. It keeps a reference to the function to apply (`tuple`) and the sequence to apply it to each item of (`newsheet1`) but doesn't actually *do* anything until you iterate over it. If you want to evaluate it right away you could consume it with e.g. `list(map(...))` but, per [what's new](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists), the list comprehension is preferred.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see so a list comprehension would be better in this case, thank you

Comment: List comprehension is more pythonic

Comment: How are you assigning to indices of a **tuple**? `sheet[0][0] = 'CHANGED'` **fails** with a `TypeError`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am creating a new list of tuples called 'newsheet2' and then making the change to the original variable 'sheet' and printing out 'newsheet2'

Comment: Right, I did miss that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe unlike for int, what kind of object, other than iterable map returns is an irrelevant implementation detail. map's contract is not 'return a map object' it's 'return an iterator'. It can return a poopsicle object, for all you know.

Comment: @jonrsharpe hmm, yeah that is fair point, it did not cross my mind they might have actually called the thing `map`, of all things. I've removed the comment since it is just confusing.